# Unable to import gtk after installing PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I can `import gtk` without any problem previously. I made a GUI in glade for GTK+ 3. Then I thought that I would like to try GTK+ 3. So I installed PyGObject. I later found out that PyGObject has little documentation and I'm using Windows (makes things worse I know).

The problem is here, I can't use `import gtk` anymore. Neither can I use `from gi.repository import Gtk`. I've tried installing PyGTK bundle again but it doesn't help.

```
    >>> import gtk

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import gtk
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
        import gobject as _gobject
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gobject\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\glib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
        from glib._glib import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like C-level library is missing, or at least in a place where the Python wrappers can't find it. Try re-installing whichever version of the C library corresponds to which Python library you would like to use (GTK2 and GTK3 *should*, theoretically, be parallel installable, but that installing the newer PyGobject broke `import gtk` suggests that at least these particular bindings aren't for some reason).

Comment: I deleted the GTKs and installed them with the GTK 2 runtime and it worked!